# Group objects within nested arrays into array of sub-totals by common property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have a problem that I can't find the way to solve.
I have a bunch of arrays that are grouped by a property:

```js
[
  [
    {Id: '211321', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 120, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '211341', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 320, Amount: 5},
    {Id: '212351', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 300, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '234121', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 230, Amount: 3},
    {Id: '223321', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 410, Amount: 1}
  ],
  [
    {Id: '2321', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 120, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '21341', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 320, Amount: 5},
    {Id: '2351', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 300, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '4121', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 230, Amount: 3},
    {Id: '3321', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 410, Amount: 1}
  ],
  [
    {Id: '3453', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 520, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '4334', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 220, Amount: 5},
    {Id: '2343', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 700, Amount: 2},
    {Id: '6654', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 430, Amount: 3},
    {Id: '4534', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 210, Amount: 1}
  ]
]
```

In this sample the objects are grouped by SendFrom property.

What I am trying to do is create an object like this:

```js
[
  {SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 1380, Amount: 13},
  {SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 1380, Amount: 13},
  {SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 2080, Amount: 13}
]
```

The new object maintains the original SendFrom value but contains updated values for the Price and Amount properties.

How can I get this with JavaScript or with help of lodash?

Best regards,
Americo

Comment: Your input does not look correct. It is neither an array nor an object. Also you did not specify "how" the you want the output updated. Will it always sum all the price and amount in a group?

Comment: Hi Rahul, yes it will always sum all the prices and amounts in a group. Regarding the input I was almost sure that it was an array of objects but I can be wrong.

Comment: Checkout @Nina Scholz solution below. It's pretty good and seems to have fixed the input as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for grouping and add all wanted values to their properties. At the end take just the values from the object.

```js
var data = [[{ Id: '211321', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 120, Amount: 2 }, { Id: '211341', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 320, Amount: 5 }, { Id: '212351', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 300, Amount: 2  }, { Id: '234121', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 230, Amount: 3 }, { Id: '223321', SendFrom: 'Customer 1', Price: 410, Amount: 1 }], [{ Id: '2321', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 120, Amount: 2 }, { Id: '21341', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 320, Amount: 5 }, { Id: '2351', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 300, Amount: 2 }, { Id: '4121', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 230, Amount: 3 }, { Id: '3321', SendFrom: 'Customer 2', Price: 410, Amount: 1 }], [{ Id: '3453', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 520, Amount: 2 }, { Id: '4334', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 220, Amount: 5 }, { Id: '2343', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 700, Amount: 2  }, { Id: '6654', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 430, Amount: 3 }, { Id: '4534', SendFrom: 'Customer 3', Price: 210, Amount: 1 }]],
    grouped = Object.values(data.flat().reduce((r, { SendFrom, Price, Amount }) => {
        r[SendFrom] = r[SendFrom] || { SendFrom, Price: 0, Amount: 0 };
        r[SendFrom].Price += Price;
        r[SendFrom].Amount += Amount;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked as I needed. And thanks @Yevgen for the explanation. I am gonna save it to study it, It is good that it works, it is better if I understand how its works

Comment: @AmericoPerez : appreciate your response, hopefully you've copied what you need as I've deleted my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(your_array_name, 'SendFrom'));
```

Comment: It's recommended to explain how your code addresses/solves the OP's question. Code only answers are frowned upon. Adding info allows visitors to quickly zoom in on the important bits, is quicker to cognitively digest, and helps fire visitors learn, and apply knowledge to their own code. This then favors Q &A for knowledge, over "give me the code" as a service Q and A. It also keeps quality high for SO as a platform.

Answer (score -1):

```
var groupBy = function(xs, key) {
  return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length'));

// => {3: ["one", "two"], 5: ["three"]}
```

Comment: consider adding some explanation to your answer.